# WPF MVVM Platform as of 2015

Tags: mvvm, prism, mvvm-light, caliburn.micro, catel

What is the best MVVM Platform when you care about modularity. I have a large application in PRISM currently which is divided into modules. Each module has the MVVM pattern implemented. I care about validation, property changed events, access to a database using Entity Framework, etc. Another large application is coming up and I am wondering if PRISM is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You will only get very opinionated answers, so here is the first one ;-)*

If you are developing a *large* application in WPF, I would always go for Catel, for the following reasons:

**Catel itself**

1. Very actively maintained, new (prerelease) builds on a daily basis
2. Very well [documented](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Catel+documentation+Home)
3. Really manages your view models life time (so you have Initializing and Closing, which allows you to unsubscribe and clean up your handlers)
4. Comes with [auditing](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Auditing) out of the box (we use that for analytics, etc)
5. [Advanced validation](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Validation) (you can merge validation contexts, etc)
6. [Entity Framework extension](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Catel.Extensions.EntityFramework) with repositories and unit of work
7. And the list goes on and on. Catel is built especially for large applications so it will really suit your needs.

**Components built on Catel**

1. [Orchestra](https://github.com/wildgums/orchestra)
   Application shell that takes care of the boilerplate code for you. Has a Fluent.Ribbon and MahApps.Metro shell. Also allows you to build your own shell on top of Orchestra. With this, you have an empty app running under 30 minutes.
2. [Orc.Controls](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.Controls)
   Lots of controls such as a DateTimePicker and TimePicker, DropDownButton, etc
3. [Orc.ProjectManagement](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.ProjectManagement)
   Handle 1 or more projects inside an application. This way your components can work with projects (an be notified of any changes) in each component without having to be aware of other components.
4. [Orc.Notifications](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.Notifications)
   Show desktop notifications from any component
5. [Orc.Anaylitics](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.Analytics)
   Automatically add Google analytics to your app (thanks to Auditing in Catel)

[And much more](https://github.com/WildGums)...

We heavily invested in Catel and all the components, it's the core of all our apps so you are sure you will receive bug fixes and feature improvements. As you can see, all the components are actively maintained (we have to, it's our core) and ready for modular WPF applications.